# Need the details of youtube video in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I need to extract the details of a given youtube link, which might include:
 1. Youtube Video,
 2. Size of video,
 3. Duration,
 4. Thumbnail image,
 5. Image - Height/width,
 6. Size of thumbnail image,
 7. Title of youtube video.

I have tried using youtube-api, but could not see if I can give the video URL and access the required details.

And other relevant details of the video. and then Need to display the video on my web page.
Which APIs are the best to use in this case.?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the youtube-api...

Comment: I have tried using youtube-api, but not sure, if I can get these details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need you can get from youtube-api. You just need to build right request with videoID from your link and parse json response, where is all data you want. Sample of such request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=k4YRWT_Aldo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```